# What do the line numbers refer to in perl -cw?

Tags: perl

When I run "perl -cw" to check syntax for my perl modules and warnings or errors are encountered, two line numbers are given:

```
perl -cw lib/My/Module.pm
Global symbol "%badvar" requires explicit package name at lib/My/Module.pm line 93, <DATA> line 132.
lib/My/Module.pm had compilation errors.
```

The "line 93" is the correct position in the source file, but what does "<DATA> line 132" refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of an error message is:

> *message* at *file* line *x*, <*handle*> line *y*.

- *message* is a description of the error.
- *file* is the file where the error occurred.
- *x* is the line number in the file where the error occurred.
- *handle* is the last file handle read from.
- *y* is the last line<sup>1</sup> read from the handle.

In your case, the error occurred at line 93 of lib/My/Module.pm, after the 132nd read of the DATA handle. DATA is the built-in handle for reading text after the `__DATA__` tag of a source file. Note that line numbers for the DATA handle are skewed. "<DATA> line 132" is the 132nd line after the `__DATA__` tag, not the 132nd line of the file.

<sub>1] Technically, it's the value of `$.`. This is normally a line number but could be something else if you've changed the value of `$/`. It's also skewed for the DATA handle.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

`<DATA>` refers to the [DATA filehandle](http://p3rl.org/SelfLoader#The___DATA___token), if you have a `__DATA__` section in your code.

I could be wrong, but I believe it also is the proper name for the filehandle you read from with the empty `<>` operator. (EDIT: I am wrong, that's `<ARGV>`! Sorry.)